# why there is databases with no RELATIONSHIP between their tables?

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I didn't ever read about ignoring RELATIONSHIPS in databases with tables that have logically relate to each other.

My question is, Not defining RELATIONSHIPS in a DB is a particular way of getting something? IMHO because of some problems like cascade update deletes or other constraints RELATIONSHIPS makes for developers.

Comment: A database without relationships is usually created by a clueless/careless person.

Comment: I've seen sloppy and/or lazy developers not define FK.  It is also possible that they got dropped in an upgrade/conversion or just by accident.

Comment: What exactly have you checked to see if the relationships do / do not exist?  Just because there is no database diagram doesn't mean there are no relationships.

Comment: Probably an old mainframer converitng to the "new technonogy" and ignoring the new, better rules.

Comment: This would be ok if it was Data Warehouse. The logical PK/FK constraints are checked during the load process, cause you don't want to Insert/Select 20 million rows and one of them causes a rollback. And if it's already checked there's no need to consume lots of resources and check it a second time.

Comment: In this case how I can recognize my question has a straight [not opinion-based] answers ?! Anyway, I reword it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Historically, one reason for not defining relationships was improving performance. Checking referential integrity takes time; some systems try to save on it, by claiming that their code has enough checks that the additional verifications inside the RDBMS itself would be redundant.

This rationale is rarely good these days. The only situation when I think it may be applicable is when the entire schema is managed by a framework-type product, with 100% generated table structures, 100% generated queries, and zero need for manual tweaking. In situations like that all you need is tables and indexes. Of course the product that manages such database as its private "storage back end" needs to be extremely reliable to avoid creating orphaned rows, dangling row references, and other unpleasant things that flourish in the absence of referential integrity checks.

When I worked on a product like that in late nineties, we never generated any referential integrity constraints. However, my experience in tracking down problems with the product has been that a significant portion of issues that we've seen in the field could have been detected early with help of referential integrity constraints. That is why I think that the "check redundancy" rationale is flawed, and should not be considered "best practice".

Answer (score 1):

**Is there any reason/best practice for not implementing relationships between tables?**

Primary and Foreign key constraints haven't always existed. (Citation needed)  Sometimes in the early days, they were maintained in code only.  Or relationships may have been implemented as unique indexes on the tables rather than PK/FK relationships.

The rational at the time was that when moving data around, key constraints became cumbersome to manage, there's an overhead associated to them, and people can do stupid things with them at times like cascade update when they shouldn't be cascaded updated because the new developer doesn't understand the whole system.

There is an overhead to primary keys they usually represent some arbitrary system assigned value that has no meaning other than to the system.  Because of the early costs of storage, databases would be designed using combined keys with information that was required to save space.  Yes, it was that important to save space.  Was it the right thing to do in terms of current database design and modeling, no.  But at the time, given the limits of systems, it was the most economical.

Now if this database was created in the past 15-20 years...  Some of those reasons go away.  If it's beyond 20 years old.  I could see why it might not have the constraints.